# Copy file from server to anoter file on same server

Tags: asp.net, file, copy

I've been searching the almight internetz for a good answer to this question but have come up with nothing at all.
I have a method that needs to copy a file on the server into a new file with another name on the same server...yeah weird I know.

When I am using File.Copy with a string holding the path with file name:

```
string newpath = (Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath) + ("Content/Images/" + p.id + ".png");
```

which returns localhost:xxxxx/Content/Images/xxx.png

But that returns a:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code. URI formats are not supported.
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this depends on the type of files you want to copy. If you want to copy just files and your application has access to both file systems and you're able to use apache Commons IO: the FileUtils class has convenient methods to copy files:

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, targetDirectory);
```

Otherwise you might consider Apache Commons VFS. It provides a common API for resources available through a number of protocols like (S)FTP, HTTP(S).

Comment: Thanks for your post. However I was using a entirely wrong approach to this problem. But I will make sure to check out your suggestion as it might prove a more efficient solution. Thanks once again.